# Google App Engine: Prevent Duplicate values, multiple field key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the datastore I want to add an entity for a parking spot.

I want to make each parking spot uniquely identified by its `latitude` and `longitude`, so no other user
can add the same parking spot or add it multiple times. I'm guessing I would do this by making the key of the entity equal to the `latitude` and `longitude` fields.

Is there any way to do this? Or do I need to make a single field? For example combine the `latitude` and `longitude` into 1 string.

In SQL terms it would be `PRIMARY KEY (latitude, longitude)`

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you sourcing your lat/long for the parking space.  If you getting it from a normal gps, you will not have the accuracy to distinguish adjacent parking spots.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/), it has built-in support for [Geopoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/geopointclass).

When a user submits new entry, you could then do a search say in a radius of 10 meters to check whether there's already something defined at that location. This will work even if users provide a slightly inaccurate lat/lon.